# How to search in two tables?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to search only in one `textbox` and if the searched `id` is equal either in the students or faculty table it will view the form and displays the data with it but I don't know how.

```
   cn.Open()

    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Familyname = '" & search.Text & "' OR Firstname = '" & search.Text & "' OR StudentID = '" & search.Text & "' OR RFID = '" & search.Text & "'"
            Searchfrm.Show()
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            dt.Clear()
            da.Fill(dt)
            cn.Close()

        Else : .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FactandStaff WHERE Familyname LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR Firstname LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR FacultyorStaffID LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR RFID LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR College LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%'"
            searchfrm2.Show()
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            dt.Clear()
            da.Fill(dt)
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: What if the textbox.text matches both tables?

Comment: sql injection, you need to learn LINQ

Comment: Why dont you Union the two tables together into one Generic Table with a field that tells you if they are faculty or students (use a case statement) and query this one table

Comment: @JamesCooke, I suppose tables are of different structure. However, he can keep separate tables and use a view to union required data

Comment: @ RezaRahmati - actually i did'nt use same id in both tables but if it did exist in the other one it should return an error message.

Comment: @mGouda - Yes, I understand the tables could be different - thus "one generic table" (using only the required data with whatever column names would be appropriate). I do agree that you could use a view as another option though

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to show a general data from both tables for example for both you want to show `FirstName` and `FamilyName` then you only need to run 1 query as below

```
"Select 1 as [type] , FirstName, LastName from Students "+
" WHERE Familyname = '" & search.Text & "' OR Firstname = '" & search.Text & "' OR StudentID = '" & search.Text & "' OR RFID = '" & search.Text & "'"+
+" Union All "
+" Select 2 , FirstName, LastName from FactandStaff )"+
+"WHERE Familyname LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR Firstname LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR FacultyorStaffID LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR RFID LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%' OR College LIKE '%" & search.Text & "%'"
```

p.s: instead of writing like this use string.format as below

```
String.Format("Select 1 as [type], FirstName, LastName from Students where Familyname = '{0}' or Firstname = '{0}' OR StudentID = {0} OR RFID = '{0}' \r Union All \r Select 2,FirstName, LastName from FactandStaff WHERE Familyname LIKE '%{0}%' OR Firstname LIKE '%{0}%' OR FacultyorStaffID LIKE '%{0}%' OR RFID LIKE '%{0}%' OR College LIKE '%{0}%'", search.Text);
```

Comment: but sir what if the id entered in the textbox is equal to either faculty or students how can i show the form?

Comment: @AlistaireTurno the query will return both records, but do you want happen if there were two records in both tables with the same firstName, in this situation what is your strategy? if you want to show error do the same if the id are same (i.e the result contains more than one record). if you want to show them all to user and user can choose between them do the same for ID too

Comment: @AlistaireTurno aslo I have added a `type` columns to query in my answer so in the result set you will understand the record is belong to which table

Comment: @AlistaireTurno It seems you need to rethink your problem... not only could you have identical id's in both tables you could have the same first name or last names.... In the past I have shown a grid of the results and then the user can click a row to go to the form with the actual person data.